# Electron absorbtion properties of ink

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

This idea has been in my mind for a while now but I can't seem to get any answers and that's mainly because of my limited theoretical background. **My question is the following**: **Would it be possible to retrieve old writings by using electron absorbtion properties of certain materials? **. An example will make this clear. Let's say I had an old written text where the ink is faded to the point where it is unreadable. Let's focus on materials like *lead* which is commonly used for writing, *water* which was used in the past as a solvent for ink and *isopropyl alcohol* which was also used as a solvent. Let's also use a *papyrus* or *parchment* as the surface on which the text is written.

When a **beam of electrons** is "shot" on the materials described above a certain radiation is expected to be emitted. Does that always have to do with **Bremsstrahlung** and **Characteristic Interaction** or does it also depend on the nature of the "target". **Also what type of wavelength would I expect to see get?** Let's assume I can achieve a variety of energies when it comes to the beam of electrons. **Would I notice any different results from different materials?**. For the simplicity of the situation let's assume that i can detect any type of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: There could be in principle many techniques able to retrieve a faded out text, at least for very small portions of it. The final part does not seem really related to the title but sounds like "what happens when we shot electrons to a material" which seem a bit broad.

Comment: @Alchimista I am mainly trying to figure out if there is an experimental method that uses electron bombarding that would help to retrieve the text.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here  http://www.ala.org/alcts/preservationweek/advice/restoringink . I think that the energy of an electron beam would be destructive to any left over ink.

Comment: Other techniques based on ir Raman or fluorescence. But unless it is some kind of 007 agent ink do not expect to retrieve text, but rather to analyse it.

Comment: @Alchimista the text is not expected to be shown on the papyrus itself but in a surface behind it. Pretty much like X ray